# convert mysql database to dynamodb model

Tags: amazon-web-services, design-patterns, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to dynamoDb and I'm trying to get the hang of it but I'm not getting how to store 'master' table details in single table dynamoDb.

For example, take this movie database.

```
category table(refer this as a master table)
+----+----------+
| id | category |  
+----+----------+
| 1  | thriller | 
+----+----------+
| 2  | horror   | 
+----+----------+
| 3  | romantic |
+----+----------+

movie table (category_id is FK)
+----+-----------+-------------+
| id | name      | category_id |  
+----+-----------+-------------+
| 1  | gone girl | 1           | 
+----+-----------+-------------+
| 2  | get out   | 1           |
+----+-----------+-------------+
| 3  | seven     | 1           |
+----+-----------+-------------+
| 4  | us        | 2           | 
+----+-----------+-------------+
| 5  | it        | 2           |
+----+-----------+-------------+
```

how to model this in dynamoDb and what would be the query if I want to get all the possible categories. Consider there are few more Fk's in the movie table.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB is a NoSQL database and the data model it uses is different from a traditional RDMS. RDMS allows you to define relationships between the tables but DynamoDB expects you to manage the relationships either combining data in a single table or to manage relationships within the application code. Your choices are

1. Add the category field within the movies table
2. Keep the two tables separate and modify applciation code to give the results with movie string type instead of id
3. Consider using a RDBMs if you are managing related data and would like to utilize JOINS